# Steps to submit the android app in Nook?

Tags: android, nook, nook-tablet

I have an app in Android.I want to publish this in NOOK market .As I Found they were two device models in Nook i.e.,NOOK Color and NOOK Tablet,Do I submit my app for both of these separately.??Could any one please help me in this ?
I googled so much But i could find any link to help me.Could any one please tell me the steps ?? And do i need to submit it separatle for both devices ??

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Barnes & Noble runs its own developer program at http://NOOKDeveloper.com and its own app store.

You have to join and then request an upgrade to NOOK App Developer to submit apps. You can make one binary for both devices, just note that it has to support Froyo (SDK8) for NOOK Color. Specs for the devices are on the website, too.

Sign up and submit for NOOK.

Tom